# insert value of single column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my MySQL database I have two tables: `customers` and `feedbacks`

Values come from a small php app.

To show to which customer a feedback record belongs, I want to insert the values of `customers.customerID` into `feedbacks.customerID`

Only single `column (customer.customerID)` into `(feedback.cutomerID)`.
Here is the DDL

```
@strawbery
-- Table structure for table `customers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `customerID` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `compid` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fbdate` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sysip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `customerID` (`customerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feedback` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerID` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `design` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `variety` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `fabric` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `stitch` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `service` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `experience` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `recommend` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_feedback` (`customerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

regards

Comment: Can we see the proper DDLs for *both* tables.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you'll need to create the customer first - if they don't exist already.

```
INSERT INTO customers ( ... ) VALUES ( ... );
```

Then insert the feedback.

```
INSERT INTO feedback (customerID, ... ) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ... );
```

However, with MySQL you *can* use a non-standard `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` trick if your customer already exists in the database:

```
INSERT INTO customers ( ... ) VALUES ( ... )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE customerID = LAST_INSERT_ID(customerID)
```

This will effectively assign the result from `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to being the specified customer id, if the customer already exists, as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html (at the bottom of the page) - if the customer didn't exist, you'll get the auto-incremented primary id for the newly created customer as you'd expect.

Then your `INSERT INTO feedback` query should work fine with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` irrespective as to whether the customer was created or updated - or you can do it at the application level with something like `PDO::lastinsertid` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 0):

Insert the ids from `customer` that aren't yet in your `feedbacks` table.

```
INSERT
  INTO feedbacks ( customerID )
SELECT c.customerID
  FROM customers c
 WHERE c.customerID NOT IN (
           SELECT f.customerID
             FROM feedbacks
       )
     ;
```

Comment: I tried it collapsar,,, but it inserts a separate record other than feedback record each time. I mean, first the insert query execute to insert feedback and then this query run to insert customerID in new record. I want it to be inserted in the same record.

Comment: ... and if there are 1000 customers and 20000 feedback lines already in the database? I get the feeling this isn't a job for a "one-off" update.

Comment: no, one customer can insert one feedback at a time.

Comment: @AmjadZahid so with you comment it is no more clear what you are asking.

Comment: @blckbird, I give you a tab running my feedback app. you enter your name, contact, email, age, gender and address[this info goes to table customers]. then you use the ui for design, variety, fabric etc of my store and submit. This info goes to table feedbacks. Now what I want is the customerID generated for you in table customers should be inserted into feedbacks.customerID where your feedback about my store is inserted. Is it clear? :)

Comment: I didn't got some adequate answer to resolve the issue!